# Hibernate, не сохраняет объект в базу

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, hibernate

**UPDATE**

Путем собственных проб и неудач я все таки решил проблему!) Все из-за невнимательности. В данном коде, который представлен ниже ничего не относиться.
Проблема была в том, что были проблемы с репозиторием сущности "ExClients".

---

Есть метод, который сохраняет объект класса ExClient в базу. Вот код вызова:

```
public void removeClient(String client_login) {
    CurrentClients currentClients = ccRepository.findByClient(client_login);
    ExClients exClients = new ExClients(currentClients.getDoctor(), currentClients.getClient());
    ecRepository.save(exClients);
    ccRepository.delete(currentClients);
}
```

Вот сам объект:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ex_clients")
public class ExClients {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer ID;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String doctor;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String client;

        public ExClients(){}

        public ExClients(String doctor, String client) {
            this.doctor = doctor;
            this.client = client;
        }

        // гетеры и сетеры 
    }
```

В чем проблема?? Как решить ? Во время создание объекта пробовал даже свои значение забивать, но все равно ничего не создает. Хотя код исполняется, так как ccRepository удаляет объект.